# Restart network interface with Ansible

Tags: regular-expression, network-interface, ansible, systemd-networkd

I have an ansible playbook which moves `.network` and `.netdev` files to the `/etc/systemd/network/` directory. Theses files are generated automatically and I can't know their names or the name/number of the interfaces that will be (automatically) created.

The `.network` and `.netdev` contains the name of the interfaces that are created :

- `00-wg0.netdev`
- `00-wg0.network`
- `10-wg1.netdev`
- `10-wg1.network`
- `20-wg2.netdev`
- `20-wg2.network`
- `[...]`

How can I (using ansible) :

- Get a list of the interfaces names like `wg0` or `wg1`... using the files which are located in `/etc/systemd/network/` ?
- Restart the interfaces (set them down, then up) using this list ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use those files? Try running the `setup` module. There should be a fact called `ansible_interfaces` listing the available interfaces.

Comment: because when I just copied the `.network` and `.netdev` the interfaces doesn't exists yet so I can't know their names except in the files name. Furthermore, I would like to avoid restarting systemd because this would break the SSH connection (I think)

Answer (score 1):

To read the files you can use [lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html):

```
vars:
  file_contents: "{{lookup('file', 'path/to/file.txt')}}"
```

To restart network interface you can use service module:

```
- name: Restart network service for vlan interface
  service:
    name: network
    state: restarted
    args: '{{ item }}'
  with_items: '{{ var_with_iface_list }}'
```